# Android SimpleCursorAdapter and Database Update

Tags: android, database

I just started with Android development and love it so far. To get
some experience, I am writing a little todo application. In my
database I have a state for a todo item, represented as int. I use a
checkbox in a list view to represent this state. To bind the data to
the view, I use a subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter. I add an
onClickListener to the checkbox that updates the state in the database
for the used list item. The problem is, if I use the following code,
the list is screwed up in the display (many items will be checked):

```
@Override
public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = inView;
  if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
       .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toodoolist_item, null);
  }
  cursor.moveToPosition(pos);
  ...

  checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        int state = 0;
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
        titleView.setPaintFlags(titleView.getPaintFlags()
            | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        titleView.setEnabled(false);
        state = 1;
     } else {
        titleView.setPaintFlags(titleView.getPaintFlags()
            ^ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        titleView.setEnabled(true);
     }

     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(TooDooTable.STATE, state); 
     context.getContentResolver()
        .update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(
     TooDooTable.CONTENT_URI, id), values, null, null);
     cursor.requery();
  }
}
```

My current workaround is to use the inflater every time, even if the
inView is not null:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view = inView;
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toodoolist_item, null);
  ...
```

This works, but I don't understand why I have to do this hack.

What would be the best practice to update the database in a
CurserAdapter and get the changes reflected immediately in the view?

Thanks

Kai

Answer (score 0):

Use [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) instead of requery, and maybe use [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) on the view if the previous method don't do anything.